# Proof regarding ternary linear code

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, coding-theory

I have to prove that all ternary linear codes must contain the all zero codeword.

Some term explanations: A linear code is a code that the sum of any two codewords must also be a codeword. In other words, for all x, y in C, x +/- y is also in C.

A ternary codeword in this exercise is a codeword containing 0, 1 or 2. Eg, 1011, 1012, 012, ... An all zero codeword is something like 0000, 000, 00000, ...

My attempt:

The addition of codewords must be done MOD 3 which means there are three allowable numbers in this MOD 3 world including 0, 1 and 2.

I am not sure about the proof. I have an idea that it must deal with the MOD 3 but not sure how to explain. Thank you so much!

Comment: If the difference of codewords is a codeword, then $x-x$ is a codeword, but that's the all-zeros word, isn't it?

Comment: @GerryMyerson it's only true for binary linear code, For example, a code containing codewords {111,000,110} : 111-111=000; 110-110=000 etc. In this code, the subtraction of some codewords yeild 000 which is also a codeword in this code. For ternary, eg. x-x also yeilds zero but that codeword is not a part of the code.

Comment: You wrote, "A linear code is a code that the sum or difference of any two codewords must also be a codeword.". So (as I wrote) if $x$ is a codeword then so is $x-x$, which is all zeros.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I'm sorry the proof should be "all linear codes must contain the all zero codeword."

Comment: If the question doesn't say what you mean for it to say, then you should edit the question. If you want to prove that all linear codes must contain the all-zero word, well, haven't I proved that for you?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I see what you meant but it's not the right answer, unfortunately.

Comment: If it's not the right answer, then it's not the right question. If you really see what I mean, then you understand that either my answer is right, or your question is wrong. Anyway, how do you know it's not the right answer? Do you know what the right answer is? If so, can you share it with us?

Comment: @GerryMyerson The answer by Joriki is correct. It must have to do mod 3. The way you explained it should have been 0+0+0 is 0 mod 3; 1+1+1 is also 0 mod 3 and 2+2+2 is also 0 mod 3.

Comment: So, as I suggested, you didn't have the question right. You still don't have the question right, as you write, "for all $x,y$ is $C$, $x\pm y$ is also in $C$." With the question written that way, $x-x=0$ is in $C$. Also, as Joriki points out, it has nothing to do with "mod $3$," it has to do with the underlying field having nonzero characteristic, so that for any $x$, if you add enough copies of $x$, at some point you get zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've now deleted the word “difference” in the question. But over a finite field, containing all sums implies containing all differences. If the code contains $x$, it contains $x+x$, $x+x+x$, etc., and over a finite field this is eventually zero. In the case of a ternary code, $x+x+x$ is zero.

Comment: Not just over a finite field, but over any field of finite characteristic. Anyway, kudos to you, joriki, for being able to figure out what OP wanted, despite all of OP's efforts to conceal it.